# BBC iPlayer radio app for Android - Wheel Navigation

Tags: java, android, xml

Does anybody have any idea how to recreate the navigation wheel in the BBC iPlayer radio shown here:

[image: wheel]

Is it done with a viewpager, graphics? Or are there any libraries available to produce something similar?

Thanks.

Comment: if there is a popular library it is likely to be found on sites like [androidviews.net](http://www.androidviews.net/). Maybe something as simple as a layout with all those buttons and a layout transformation (rotate) is enough to create that

Comment: I have searched the web to try and find a library that accomplishes something similar but have drawn a blank. Wondering if anyone is perhaps currently working on a library to do this ?

Comment: I'm the author of the suggested library. My library will be a good start but you will probably need a ViewPager or some other mechanism to cycle the views above the wheel. You also need to consider the touch events, since my library only allows the wheel to drag within the wheel's bounds. I have a working implementation by using a Custom ViewPager and OnPageChangeListener and allowing the ViewPager to handle all touch events, then calling setAngle() on the wheelView. Edit: I notice this post was over a year ago now :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late however a new library has recently been posted on GitHub that does exactly what I required.

https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView